# Progress : Connection fails with dbDelUsrctl: SemLockLog Error 13

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

When I try to connect with the "data manager" on a running progress database (openedge 10.1C)
I get the error dbDelUsrctl: SemLockLog error 13 on the log file.
The openedhe runs on Windows server 2008.
Now the logfile exists but it is 4GB big.
The rights on the file are ok.
I can perfectly connect to other databases on the same system.

How can I solve this ?

Thx
K

Answer (score 2):

Is the .lg file exactly 4GB?  Problems that occur when files hit powers of two are always suspicious.

Either way try:

1) Truncate the .lg file (prolog dbname [-online]) and try again.

or

2) Or copy/rename it if you want to preserve it.

And follow Jensd's advice.

Answer (score 1):

1) Double check permissions again. Error 13 generally means that you don't have permission to access a file. Check the folders as well as the files.

2) Try to connect as root (or administrator since you're on Windows).

3) Search the [Progress KnowledgeBase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/). There are several entries for your specific error.

Even if the log file is 4GB you should be able to open it even if it takes some time (or get a windows utility similar to "tail").